# How to list and download metadata from GCS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-shell

I hava a Google Cloud Storage instance and need to get a txt file with the metadata from my files

I have two paths in my GCS enviroment, i need to list the metadata from the files in each path and copy it to a local txt file, i can list all the metadata but can't copy to local file, i've used the code below to list the metadata and it works, but i don't know how to copy this.

gsutil ls -L gs://my_bucket/images/**

it lists all my metadata i just want this information on a local txt file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to use the command that I shared be aware that you can not write directly to a bucket, so I recommend you choose another folder like home for example, for work with buckets from console there are specialized gsutil commands[1], neverthless, you can use a script to store the .txt file in the bucket.

```
#!/bin/bash
gsutil ls -L gs://my_bucket/directory/** > /home/directory/metadata.txt 
gsutil cp /home/directory/metadata.txt gs://mybucket
```

you can save this lines in a .sh file:

/home/script.sh

and later execute the script:

sh script.sh

this allow to you to save metadata on the bucket in a .txt file

[1] https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use this command on Cloud shell:

```
gsutil ls -L gs://my_bucket/folder/** > /home/other_folder/metadata.txt
```

This command allows to you write the outcome of `gsutil` and write a file where you need.

To download the file you can use download file option from Cloud shell and get metadata information you need.

Comment: Hello! I've created a new folder inside my bucket and uploaded an empty metadata.txt file.  tried to use "gsutil ls -L gs://my_bucket/images/** > gs://my_bucket/Metadata/metadata.txt" but it says that the directory or the file doesn't exists.

Comment: Hello, I left another answer in the post